# Customised Infowindow not working?

Tags: android

Im trying to customize my Infowindow, but I cant bind the TextViews with the strings. The InfoWindow sometimes shows the raw xml, sometimes just not working. I feel myself a little bit lost.

The loading function seems to be working fine. In my opinion the problem begins at the mMap.addMarker function.

```
private void placeAllMarkers() {

    mContext = getActivity();
    mPrefManager = new PrefManager(mContext);
    List <MapMarker> allMapMarker;

    allMapMarker = mPrefManager.loadAllMapMarker();

    if (allMapMarker.size() > 0) {

        for (int counter = 0; counter < allMapMarker.size(); counter++) {

            price = allMapMarker.get(counter).getSum();
            shop = allMapMarker.get(counter).getShop();
            date = allMapMarker.get(counter).getDate();
            Float GPS_X = allMapMarker.get(counter).getGPS_X();
            Float GPS_Y = allMapMarker.get(counter).getGPS_Y();

            LatLng Position = new LatLng(GPS_X, GPS_Y);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(Position)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    InfoView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

                    setShop = (TextView) InfoView.findViewById(R.id.setShop);
                    setSum = (TextView) InfoView.findViewById(R.id.setSum);
                    setDate = (TextView) InfoView.findViewById(R.id.setDate);

                    setShop.setText(shop);
                    setSum.setText(price);
                    setDate.setText(date);

                    return InfoView;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    return null;
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT

It is something with the strings:

> > FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >                                                                             Process: hu.mosomaci.flagsproject, PID: 4983
> >                                                                             android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xd98
> >                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:252)
> >                                                                                 at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:108)
> >                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
> >                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3895)
> >                                                                                 at hu.mosomaci.flagsproject.fragments.MapForFlags$1.getInfoContents(MapForFlags.java:136)
> >                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.zzi(Unknown Source)
> >                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzd$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
> >                                                                                 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all set your marker like below. Set snippet for both price and date and add % sign between them.

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(Position)  
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
.title(shop)
.snippet(price + "%"+date));
```

Try to set the text and other work inside `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` methode ( as `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` is used to define the content.) instead of `getInfoWindow(Marker marker)` of `setInfoWindowAdapter`.

And when setting text to TextView split the snippet and get price and date by index

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
               return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    InfoView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

                    TextView setShop = (TextView) InfoView.findViewById(R.id.setShop);
                    TextView setSum = (TextView) InfoView.findViewById(R.id.setSum);
                    TextView setDate = (TextView) InfoView.findViewById(R.id.setDate);

                    String snippet = marker.getSnippet(); 
                    String[] splited_text = snippet.split("%"); 
                    String price = splited_text[0]; 
                    String date = splited_text[1];

                    setShop.setText(marker.getTitle());
                    setSum.setText(price);
                    setDate.setText(date);

                    return InfoView;
                }
            });
```

Comment: I used your edit and implemented with this, and now its working, but the price and the date contains both.                           `setShop.setText(marker.getTitle());
setSum.setText(marker.getSnippet());
setDate.setText(marker.getSnippet());`

Comment: Can I add somehow one more separated snippet?

Comment: you can use strings or parse html inside snipet

Comment: I have only 2 fields, that i can handle (title and snippet), but i have 3 strings. (shop, price, date). What can i do in this case?

Comment: set snippet for both shop and date and add % sign between them and when setting text split them and get by index
`snippet(price + "%"+date));
String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
String[] splited_text = snippet.split("%");
String shop = splited_text[0];
String date = splited_text[1];`

Comment: Lol, you are a mastermind. It is working. Could you please edit your answer to make it 100% clear? Then I will accept it. By the way Thanks for your idea:)